# Question about constructing the Weierstrass $\wp$ function

Tags: number-theory, complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convergence of a particular series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178388/convergence-of-a-particular-series)

I am reading about the construction of the Weierstrass $\wp$-function for an arbitrary lattice in $\mathbb{C}$. If $a, b$ are complex nonzero numbers with $a/b \not\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\Lambda = \{ma + nb: m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subset \mathbb{C}$, why does $$\sum_{\omega \in \Lambda - \{0\}}\frac{1}{|\omega|^{3}}$$ converge?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the answer [to this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/178388/32441) should help you here.

Comment: @OldJohn: while it is not an exact duplicate, the question you refer to is more general. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, I agree - should we vote to close this as a duplicate? (I am never totally sure of the correct procedure in these cases).