# Sum of reciprocials of square distance over integer lattice

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I show that for $(n,m) \in \Bbb{Z}^2-0$ $$\sum_{n^2+m^2 \le R^2} \frac{1}{n^2+m^2} = 2\pi \log R + O(1) \quad as \quad R\to \infty$$

Comment: I think I found a method. Comparing with $\int \int 1/(x^2+y^2)$ would be work.

Comment: Possibly relevant is [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/178388/32441) - if you take the lattice to be the Gaussian integers.